# How to get country specific result with Google autocomplete place api ios sdk?

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-places-api, gmsplace

I'm using below method to get autocomplete result for input string of GMSPlacesClient class:

```
- (void)autocompleteQuery:(NSString *)query
               bounds:(GMSCoordinateBounds * GMS_NULLABLE_PTR)bounds
               filter:(GMSAutocompleteFilter * GMS_NULLABLE_PTR)filter
             callback:(GMSAutocompletePredictionsCallback)callback
```

I tried to implement bounds by multiple ways but none of them worked, I wonder if there is any standard way to get country specific results with GMSCoordinateBounds?

Answer (score 34):

You can get the country specific results with the Google autocomplete place api iOS SDK. Just go to this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically)

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .Establishment
filter.country = "UK"
```

set the filter country to what ever the country code you want. This will then fetch only country specific results for you.

You can obtain the country codes from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, In my Google maps SDK for iOS which are from pods written in Objective C. Does not have the property like "country". Any suggestion.

Comment: filter.country = "AU" not working for me. Please help me.

Comment: let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .Establishment
    filter.country = "SG"
    placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchString, bounds: nil, filter: filter) { (results, error:NSError?) -> Void in
      self.resultsArray.removeAll()
      if let _ = results {
        for result in results!{
          if let res: GMSAutocompletePrediction = result {
           // your code
          }
        }
      }
    }

Comment: You guys might want to remove the `filter.type = .Establishment` line (or `.establishment` for swift 3+) as that is also only listing "Business results" per the code docs from Google.

Comment: Saved the day. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In your google places API url, just append

```
 &components=country:sg 
here sg = country code for singapore. Append country code as per your requirement.
```

The country must be passed as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code. you can refer [Country code Of different countries](http://data.okfn.org/data/core/country-list)

Answer (score 4):

This one work for me

```
let placesClient = GMSPlacesClient()
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = .Establishment
    filter.country = "SG"
    placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchString, bounds: nil, filter: filter) { (results, error:NSError?) -> Void in
      self.resultsArray.removeAll()
      if let _ = results {
        for result in results!{
          if let res: GMSAutocompletePrediction = result {
           // your code
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

in **Swift 5** and later

you can custom your search by configuring the `GMSAutocompleteFilter`, and specify the country from its attribute `country`

example :

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.country = "MA"
autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

the country should be a ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code (case insensitive).

you can find those codes from here: [Countries ISO Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google autocomplete Places API for iOS doesn't support filtering by country. `GMSCoordinateBounds` uses the northEast and southWest bounds corresponding to the rectangular region defined by the two corners.

It might be easier to use [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete?hl=en) and filter with `components=country:` You can specify what country you want after `country:`

Answer (score 0):

The full list of country codes can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Use it with:

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.country = "YOURCountryCode"
```